# SonarQube with new Branch feature fails with "a measure can be set only once for a specific Component"?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Trying out the newer branch support feature in SonarQube.

I have run into a bit of a problem which I do not understand.

I upgraded our SonarQube instance to the developer edition. Under the branch configuration for Long living branches pattern I set it to (develop|master) as we are using GitFlow branching strategy.

From a Jenkins job I executed the following after upgrading to the developer edition where I Pass the project key and name in. This works fine and I get an analysis for the website project shown.

```
C:\Jenkins\sitecore\develop>SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe" begin /d:sonar.login=******** /k:NEON /n:Website /v:Build#3-SHA#a37bc8060e8d5a4264140784b1f93c9a4ca80b43 /d:sonar.host.url=http://codeanalysis.remoteiv.dk /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=C:\Jenkins\sitecore\develop\NUnitResult.xml /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=C:\Jenkins\sitecore\develop\OpenCoverResult.xml
```

Then for subsequent runs Jenkins passes the feature branch name using the sonar.branch.name property as shown below.

```
C:\Jenkins\sitecore\feature-NEON-10-Setting-Up-Toll-Gate@2>SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe" begin /d:sonar.login=********** /k:NEON /n:Website /v:Build#5-SHA#2acea67103ab4b1223d80bf62d23999dd5369c29 /d:sonar.branch.name=feature-NEON-10-Setting-Up-Toll-Gate /d:sonar.host.url=http://codeanalysis.remoteiv.dk /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=C:\Jenkins\sitecore\feature-NEON-10-Setting-Up-Toll-Gate@2\NUnitResult.xml /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=C:\Jenkins\sitecore\feature-NEON-10-Setting-Up-Toll-Gate@2\OpenCoverResult.xml
```

The end step in Jenkins says it succeeds.

```
INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp] (done) | time=30ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=341ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Skipping CPD calculation for short living branch
INFO: Analysis report generated in 378ms, dir size=841 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 61ms, zip size=55 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 49ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://codeanalysis.remoteiv.dk/dashboard/index/NEON
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://codeanalysis.remoteiv.dk/api/ce/task?id=AWL3Sf5q5_IkahY6f6q6
INFO: Task total time: 1:02.311 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:04.661s
INFO: Final Memory: 23M/692M
```

But The analysis says it has failed on the server and there is no branch under the branches view on sonar server?

The error is.

```
{"task":{"id":"AWL3Sf5q5_IkahY6f6q6","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AWL3Mrk25_IkahY6f6qw","componentKey":"NEON","componentName":"Website","componentQualifier":"TRK","status":"FAILED","submittedAt":"2018-04-24T12:54:04+0200","submitterLogin":"jenkins","startedAt":"2018-04-24T12:54:05+0200","executedAt":"2018-04-24T12:54:15+0200","executionTimeMs":10155,"logs":false,"errorMessage":"a measure can be set only once for a specific Component (key=NEON:BRANCH:feature-NEON-10-Setting-Up-Toll-Gate), Metric (key=test_execution_time). Use update method (Visit failed for Component {key=NEON:BRANCH:feature-NEON-10-Setting-Up-Toll-Gate,type=PROJECT} )","hasScannerContext":true,"organization":"default-organization","branch":"feature-NEON-10-Setting-Up-Toll-Gate","branchType":"SHORT"}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the following bug that will be fixed in the next version of SonarQube: [SONAR-9384](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9384)

A temporary workaround I found is the following:

1. Go to your project "Administration > General Settings" page
2. Search for the setting `sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths`
3. Specify a dumb value, like `foo`

With this, the analyzer won't try to persist unit test information so this won't fail. The downside is that you will not have unit test measures - which IMO is perfectly acceptable compared to not having analyses at all.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was testing the new branch stuff with a trial license. So I think I will roll back to the CE version and the old way with sonar.branch. The SonarQube static analysis is part of our CI/CD tollgate being ran by Jenkins. We are using it to merge feature branches into out integration branch and the UT coverage is an important measure for us to allow a feature branch into our integration branch.

Comment: I think this is definitely an issue around short lived branches, we are using SonarCloud with VSTS and this is happening on our pull request scans, but I can run a long-life branch/master through the same CI build and it will work absolutely fine. @fabrice-sonarsource-team does your team have a rough timescale for getting this fixed?

Comment: Our team is on it, hopefully we'll deploy a fix soon.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam We are using Community EditionVersion 8.9.6 (build 50800), but we are still getting this error. Even though it should be fixed in 7.2. :-(